# timeout между созданием процессов python multiprocessing

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-7, multiprocessing

Здравствуйте.Моя функция  gettin_high применяется  к каждому элементу из списка qwer.Создаются процессы по 5 штук поочередно.Можно ли сделать таймаут между созданиями этих процессов или,может быть можно добавить ожидание закрытия,а после создание следующих по списку.Огромная просьба помочь,пожалуйста.Как создаю процессы:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def gettin_high(x):
....
if __name__=='__main__':
    qwer = open('qwer.txt','r').readlines()
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    results = pool.map(gettin_high, qwer)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: ничего непонятно ;) что работает не так? почему вы решили что процессы создаются поочередно? зачем таймаут? ожидание закрытия чего? создание чего и по какому списку?

Comment: ThreadPool создаёт потоки. Чтобы ограничить количество вызовов вашей функции за выбранный промежуток времени, [можно семафор использовать (RatedSemaphore)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16686329)